# Memory leaks while showing toast from other class

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I'm using leak canary for detecting memory leaks. From my activity, I'm calling a method from other class for updating data in **firebase realtime-database**, on `addOnCompleteListener()` I'm showing a success toast, and on `addOnFailureListener()` showing error toast. As toast requires context I've extended `Application` to get **Application context**, I haven't passed context form my activity, because reading some article I came to know that passing context can cause a memory leak. Here is my class for updating in the database.

```java
public class FirebaseUpdaterr extends Application {

    private Context context;
    private DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    private FirebaseUser user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    public FirebaseUpdaterr(){
        this.context=getApplicationContext();
    }
    public void retriveBook(String bookId, final BookInfo bookInfo){

        final Book[] book = new Book[1];
        ref.child("Books").child(bookId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                book[0] =dataSnapshot.getValue(Book.class);
                bookInfo.onCallback(book[0]);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void accept(final BookRequestData bookRequestData){

        retriveBook(bookRequestData.getReqBookId(), new BookInfo() {
            @Override
            public void onCallback(Book book) {


                Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();

                childUpdates.put("/Books/"+bookRequestData.getReqBookId(),book);
                childUpdates.put("/Requests/"+bookRequestData.getReqId()+"/status",StaticValues.REQUESTE_ACCEPTED);
                ref.updateChildren(childUpdates)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                    Toasty.success( context, bookRequestData.getReqUserName()+"'s request accepted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();

                                }
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toasty.error(context, bookRequestData.getReqUserName()+"'s request is not accepted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
                            }
                        });

            }
        });

    }
}
```

My `BookInfoActivity` is large. I've added only possible reason for `Memory leaks`.

```java
public class BookInfoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      BookViewModelFactory modelFactory=new BookViewModelFactory(bookLight.getBookId());
      BookViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,modelFactory).get(BookViewModel.class);

      LiveData<Book> liveData = viewModel.getBookLiveData();
       liveData.observe(this, new Observer<Book>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Book bookLive) {
               //other stuffs
           }

       checkSameReq(new FirebaseCallBack() {
            @Override
            public void onCallback(final BookRequestData reqData) {
                requestBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
                {
                  if(requested){
                      FirebaseUpdaterr fireUpdate=new FirebaseUpdaterr();
                      fireUpdater.accept(bookRequest);
                    }
                   }
                });
              }
        });

    }



  private void checkSameReq( final FirebaseCallBack firebaseCallBack) {
        ref = mdatabase.getReference();
        sameReqCheck=ref.child("Users").child(book.getOwnerID()).child("pendingRequest").orderByChild("reqUserId").equalTo(user.getUid());
        sameReqCheckValEventListener=new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                boolean sameReqCheck=false;
                final BookRequestData[] requestData = {null};
                Log.e("shanto2", String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()));
                for (DataSnapshot reqSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    BookRequestData bookRequestData=reqSnapshot.getValue(BookRequestData.class);
                    if(bookRequestData.getReqBookId().equals(book.getBookId())){

                        sameReqCheck=true;
                        requestData[0] =bookRequestData;
                        break;

                    }

                }

                if(!sameReqCheck){
                    requestBooks.setText(REQUEST_BOOK);
                }else{

                    requestBooks.setText(CANCEL_REQUEST);

                }
                bookStatusSetter(book);

                if(book.getAcceptedReqId().length()>0){
                     requestRef=ref.child("Requests").child(book.getAcceptedReqId());
                    reqEventListener=new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            BookRequestData bookRequestData=dataSnapshot.getValue(BookRequestData.class);


                            if(book.getCurrentOwnerId().equals(user.getUid()) && bookRequestData.getStatus()==StaticValues.REQUESTE_ACCEPTED){
                                requestBooks.setText(GOT_IT);
                                requestData[0] =bookRequestData;
                            }
                            firebaseCallBack.onCallback(requestData[0]);


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    };
                    requestRef.addValueEventListener(reqEventListener);
                }else {
                    firebaseCallBack.onCallback(requestData[0]);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        };

        sameReqCheck.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(sameReqCheckValEventListener);

    }

}
```

After inspecting with **leakcanary** I've found following logs, Where is the error?

[image: Logs of leak canary]

Comment: Without seeing the code from your app, it's not really possible to discern where your leak is.

Comment: @a_local_nobody I've some other leaks would you please tell me wheater they are from my code or library?(i.imgur.com/G7WDpL0.png) is it leak for using glide? Why I'm getting ReportFragmentLeak (imgur.com/YNgH0xD.png)?

Answer (score 1):

The provided leak trace shows no code of yours, this is most likely an Android leak. It could be a bug in AOSP, or a bug in a manufacturer implementation. You can provide this information to LeakCanary (https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/new/choose => Leak in Android SDK / support library) and provide the Android API version and manufacturer so that it gets tagged as a "library leak" in future releases.

Comment: thanks. I was getting lots of these leaks. I've some other leaks would you please tell me wheater they are from my code or library?(https://i.imgur.com/G7WDpL0.png) is it leak for using glide? Why I'm getting `ReportFragmentLeak`  (https://imgur.com/YNgH0xD.png)?

Answer (score 0):

Store app context It is not a good practice but It should not cause a memory leak because you only have 1 app instance . It is difficult to see what is happening but inline listeners and callbacks should be avoided. I suggest store listeners and callbacks in prívate attributes. Init them when activity is started and then put them to null when activity is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
But the problem is not the Toast, but the context, so I created an extended function, where I leave the context as global, and use the local context to show the toast. take a look

Extension.kt

```
import android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
import android.widget.Toast
import android.view.View

fun Context.toast(text: String, duration: Int = LENGTH_SHORT) {
    Toast.makeText(
        applicationContext,
        text,
        duration
    ).show()
}

fun Context.toastCustom(text: String, durationCustom: Int = LENGTH_SHORT) {
    Toast(applicationContext).apply {
        duration = durationCustom
        view = View.inflate(applicationContext, R.layout.custom_toast, null)
        val textV = view?.findViewById(R.id.toastCustomTv) as TextView
        textV.text = text
        show()
    }
}
```

from Activity call

```
 toast("message to toast", LENGTH_SHORT)
```

from Fragment call

```
 requireContext().toast("message to toast", LENGTH_SHORT)
```

from Composable call

```
 val localContext = LocalContext.current
 localContext.toastCustom("message to toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
```

Toasts is leaking not anymore